# Why is this implementation of merge sort of 1,000,000 taking so long?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mergesort

I'm testing it with 1,000,000 numbers, and it's just kind of hanging. I thought it would breeze through 1,000,000 easily. Is it my implementation? I have a feeling it's because of the `slice()`, anyone have an idea?

Edit:
Just got this message:
`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory`

```
TopDownSplitMerge(numbersArray);
function TopDownSplitMerge(arrayOfNumbers) {     
    var length = arrayOfNumbers.length
    var middleIndex = parseInt(length/2);

    if(length <= 1) {
        return arrayOfNumbers;
    }                       

    // Split left side
    var left = TopDownSplitMerge(arrayOfNumbers.slice(0, middleIndex));  

    // Split right side
    var right = TopDownSplitMerge(arrayOfNumbers.slice(middleIndex, length));   

    // Merge every back together
    return TopDownMerge(left, right);
}

function TopDownMerge(left, right) {
    var results = []

    while(left.length || right.length) {
        console.log("looping...");

        // Check if both sides are NOT empty, if so, then just finish shifting the non-empty side
        if(left.length && right.length) { 
            if(left[0] <= right[0]) {
               results.push(left.shift()) 
            } else {
               results.push(right.shift()) 
            }
        } else if(left.length) {
           results.push(left.shift()) 
        } else {
           results.push(right.shift()) 
        }

    }

    console.log("Merging....", results.length);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: Have you tried your code with just a few numbers to see if it works correctly?

Comment: It fails to sort `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: @TedHopp I tested it and it worked perfectly at 1,000 numbers.

Comment: Slicing creates a new array, so you are creating lots of copies of your array. Also, shifting moves every element of the array, which is also slow for large arrays.

Comment: @thefourtheye You're right, the index was offset by the -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things I had to change

```
var right = TopDownSplitMerge(arrayOfNumbers.slice(middleIndex, length));

....
....
....

function TopDownMerge(left, right) {
    var results = [], leftLen = left.length, rightLen = right.length;

    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < leftLen || j < rightLen;) {
        if (i < leftLen && j < rightLen) {
            if(left[i] <= right[j]) {
                results.push(left[i]);
                i += 1;
            } else {
                results.push(right[j]);
                j += 1;
            }
        } else if (i < leftLen) {
            results.push(left[i]);
            i += 1;
        } else {
            results.push(right[j]);
            j += 1;
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

**Edit:** Now I changed it to accept indices instead of sliced arrays and it boosts the performance more.

```
function TopDownSplitMerge(arrayOfNumbers, start, end) {
    var length = end - start;
    var middleIndex = start + parseInt(length / 2);

    if (length <= 1) {
        return [arrayOfNumbers[start]];
    }

    // Split left side
    var left = TopDownSplitMerge(arrayOfNumbers, start, middleIndex);

    // Split right side
    var right = TopDownSplitMerge(arrayOfNumbers, middleIndex, length);

    // Merge every back together
    return TopDownMerge(left, right);
}
TopDownSplitMerge(numbersArray, 0, numbersArray.length);
```

Jsperf: http://jsperf.com/so-q-19341534

jsperf for my solution with 10,000,000 numbers: http://jsperf.com/solution-to-so-q-19341534

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense. The shift was killing it too!

Comment: For even more speed, you could pass in a "destination array" + start index and push directly into that, instead of concatting them together

Comment: How did you calculate the time performance? I'm just using the difference of time.

Comment: @Strawberry Please check the jsperf results now.

Comment: @thefourtheye niceee! I left a comment too :D

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right. `slice()` copies the array, so you're effectively copying the array bajillions of times. And then your `shift`ing the front off the array, which requires copying the array each time--a bajillion more times. A better approach could be to pass in the index range for the 'splitting'.

Comment: So much for trying to be clever with JS functions... :(